# Why do we push knees out into forearms when deadlifting?

Tags: deadlifts

This is a step mentioned in some deadlifting tutorials I read. I can't get why this is done. Could someone elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It is a cue for external rotation at the hip which engages the glutes.

One of the functions of the glutes is the externally rotate your femurs. Cuing “knees into forearms” contracts your glutes, which tightens up your posterior chain and prepares you for initiating the pull. In the deadlift, tightness is strength.